# Make first value in dropdown bold in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a dropdown where I need to make first value in the dropdown to be bold.Dropdown code is as follows.

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <select-box id="ad-version-select" options="curItem.stats.version" model="state.version" initial="All" change="watchvalue()" ng-disabled="state.partialDisable"></select-box>
</div>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="model" ng-change="change()">

    <option ng-if="initial.length" ng-bind="initial" value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{getValue()}}" ng-selected="model==getValue()" ng-bind="getTitleVariable()"></option>
</select>
```

I tried like

```
<style>
div.col-xs-3>div:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

but didn't worked. I am not getting any idea how to make only the first value bold. I can't use jquery. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: not hard to see that css selector has nothing to do with `<select>` or `<option>`

Answer (score 1):

There need to be an alteration done in your css selector. You should select the first child of the option to make it bold.

```
option:first-child
{
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Here is the sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrx9smct/)

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Comment: That was a general solution to the problem. If you can upload a Fiddle for your question then we can dig in it.

Comment: This code is having more of angular part and less javascript . I am new to all these and my attempts to set up fiddle with this code, failed.

Comment: Try to add a class to the select and in that class add that css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-options with ng-class:

```
<select ng-model="Blah">
  <option ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="{red: person.id == 1}" ng-selected="{Blah == person.Name}">{{person.Name}}</option>  
</select>

app.controller('AppController',
[
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
      {id: 1, Name:'John',Eligible:true},
      {id: 2,Name:'Mark',Eligible:true},
      {id: 3,Name:'Sam',Eligible:false},
      {id: 4, Name:'Edward',Eligible:false},
      {id: 5, Name:'Michael',Eligible:true}
    ];

    $scope.Blah = 'Sam';

  }
]);
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2lyKZtIadvuCkYF6S865?p=preview)

Comment: What if the ID changes? Or the object structure? Really should use ng-repeats $index instead of doing this.

Comment: It's just an example. Of course you can use this `ng-class="{red: $index == 0}"`

Answer (score 0):

@Help's solution should work.
But not all browsers support styles in `<select><option>`. Maybe you need to build the component by yourself, something like this:

```html
<div class="select">
  <div class="selected" ng-bind="current.title"></div>
  <div class="options">
    <div class="option" ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}" ng-bind="option.title" ng-click="current=option"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.option:first-child {font-weight: bold;}
```

You'll need to add some more scripts and styles to make it work like a natural `<select>`.